# How do I properly allow user jenkins to write to a specific directory under user minecraft home directory?

Tags: permissions, cp, move, jenkins

I am using Jenkins, I want to copy a file from the Jenkins directory in to the *minecraft* user directory, but I am not sure how to go about this, as when I run

```
cp build/versions/*.info /home/*minecraft*/www/files/Minecraft/versions
```

I get 'Permission Denied'

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please [edit] your question to clarify 1) what user is running the `cp` command; 2) permission denied to _what_? The source directory or the target? 3) What are the permissions on the target directory? Ideally, add the output of this command: `d=/home/minecraft/www/files/Minecraft/versions; while [[ "$d" =~ home ]] ; do ls -ld $d; d=${d%/*}; done`.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way would be using groups.  User Jenkins is added to the the minecraft-group (the corrosponding group for user minecraft). Then the minecraft-user gives the minecraft-group write-permissions for the directory in question (eg. `chmod g+w ~minecraft/some_directory`).  Of course it's also possible (for root) to create a custom group just be used with this directory (eg. a new group minewriters or something).  If the minecraft-user is the administrator og the minecraft-group, he can add users to the group with `gpasswd -a user group` ( `gpasswd -a jenkins minecraft` ) - else root must add users to the group.

A newer, better and more fine-tuned way (though a bit complex) is using Access Control Lists (acl), where the owner of a file or directory can give specific users and/or groups access to a file or directory.  The minecraft-user would just add jenkins to the "access-list" of the directory in question, and give jenkins write-permissions to the directory.

`setfacl -m user:jenkins:rwx ~minecraft/some_directory`

This will give the user jenkins the right to create new files (w), list the contens with ls (r) and change into the directory (x).

+++

Access to files and directories are somewhat dependent on the users' access to the directories above.  If user jenkins can't enter the home-directory of user minecraft (/home/minecraft), then he can't access any directories under it either... even if he has been given permission with `chmod` or `setfacl` to the particular directory.

So user minecraft must implicitely or explicitely also give user jenkins *at least* execute (x) permission to his home-directory (and all directories between his home-directory and the directory jenkins shall be allowed to write to).  Execute permission for a directory, gives the right to "enter" the directory (eg. with the `cd` command).  Most user will also appriciate having read-permission (r) - which gives them the right to list directory-content with commands like `ls` - so they can orient themselves.

If the permissions of minecraft's home-directory already is 'rwxr-x---' or 'rwxr-xr-x' (which is often is) that is enough... if it's 'rwx------' then access must be modified to give at least members of the minecraft-group - or user jenkins - access.

+++

It's also a good idea to add the sticky-bit to the directory jenkins should be allowed to write to (ie. `chmod a+t ~minecraft/some_directory` ).  This prevents users with write-permissions to a directory from deleting files belonging to *other* users (with the exception of the directory's owner, which still may delete any files).