# Jenkins write permission on linux

Tags: linux, jenkins

I'm having trouble getting Jenkins to write to a directory, however I believe I have set the correct permissions. Jenkins is being run by a user named "jenkins", who belongs to a group called "jenkins-group". The directory in question looks something like this when I `ll`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 jenkins-group jenkins-group 68 Sep 3 13:01 test_save_data_jenkins_R
```

I followed the recommended approach as seen in the link below, by creating a group having "rwx" permissions and adding the user running Jenkins to this group. [How do I properly allow user jenkins to write to a specific directory under user minecraft home directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141139/how-do-i-properly-allow-user-jenkins-to-write-to-a-specific-directory-under-user).

So I have given the group "jenkins-group" rwx permissions, which in turn should give the user "jenkins" those permissions as well, since it has this group as a secondary. When I log in to the user "jenkins" from a terminal I'm able to create a new file in this folder using `touch test.txt`. However when I run a build from Jenkins with the following commands in execute shell:

```
cd /apps/models/test_save_data_jenkins_R && whoami && touch test.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
+ cd /apps/models/test_save_data_jenkins_R
+ whoami
jenkins
+ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘test.txt’: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Notice that the group "jenkins-group" also has rwx permissions to the folders "apps" and "models". I have tried giving the user "jenkins" direct permission using the following command:

```
$ setfacl -Rm user:jenkins:rwx /apps/models/test_save_data_jenkins_R/
```

which would result in the script running successfully. However this is really a workaround, and I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong in the previous approach.

#### Update #1

Running `groups jenkins`:

```
jenkins : jenkins jenkins-group
```

And running `getfacl` returns:

```
# file: test_save_data_jenkins_R/
# owner: jenkins-group
# group: jenkins-group
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

#### Update #2

Running /usr/bin/id in jenkins script gives:

```
+ /usr/bin/id 
uid=775(jenkins) gid=895(jenkins) groups=895(jenkins)
```

Running /usr/bin/id from terminal gives:

```
uid=775(jenkins) gid=895(jenkins) groups=895(jenkins),1012(jenkins-group)
```

Notice this happens as well after running safeRestart of jenkins service.

Comment: Isn't test_save_data_jenkins_R owned by jenkins-group jenkins-group instead of jenkins jenkins-group?

Comment: Ok - therefore huge question can you manually go into a path and create file whilst being that user? either you all set rules for folder - but without -R so rights only did stay on folder - not on files/subfolders, or script is running as someone else.

Comment: Yes i can manually add files and remove them as user "jenkins" in the directory. I am perplexed since when I run the script and ask "whoami" it says jenkins.

Comment: Can you add an `/usr/bin/id` to your script? There is any difference between the `id` outputs when run interactively or in the script?

Comment: @andcoz I get the following output:
+ /usr/bin/id
uid=775(jenkins) gid=895(jenkins) groups=895(jenkins)
--- However running this from the jenkins user gives: uid=775(jenkins) gid=895(jenkins) groups=895(jenkins),1012(jenkins-group)

Comment: What if you add `chgrp jenkins-group` to the script?

Comment: Please add this information to your question. It seems that when run by jenkins, your script is **not** member of `jenkins-group`. This explains why it cannot create the file.

Comment: @andcoz - he added it, the user jenkins is in that group.

Comment: `id` is clear: the user is in the group but the script, when run by jenkins program, is not in the `jenkins-group` group. Now, we have to look for an explanation of this. How do you start jenkins server? Systemd?

Comment: Did you restarted jenkins server after you added jenkins user to the group?

Comment: Yes i understand the issue as well now. I tried running a safeRestart of the jenkins service, however the outcome is unchanged. I updated the original post to reflect this @andcoz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the user permissions were not reflected until i restarted the jenkins service. I did this on the red hat linux machine by typing:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```